# Where can i find Event Hubs-compatible path, and service primary key of the IoT hub in azure portal

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azureportal

Azure IoT Edge Quick Start says we can get the Event Hubs-compatible path, and service primary key from the IOThub using Azure Cli:

```
az iot hub show --query properties.eventHubEndpoints.events.path --name YourIoTHubName

az iot hub policy show --name service --query primaryKey --hub-name YourIoTHubName
```

Is there any other way access these values from azure portal or powershell.
When i run these command from powershell, it says az is not

> az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have installed AZ Module. But still throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the portal, go to your IoT hub. Then in **Settings**, go to **Built-in endpoints**. Here you can find the **Event Hub-compatible name** and **Event Hub-compatible endpoint**. The **Event Hub-compatible name** is the path you need. The **Event Hub-compatible endpoint** includes the primary key.

You can also find the primary key if you go to your IoT hub's **Shared access policies** in **Settings**. Select **service** to get the service key.